# The number of class labels must be greater than one

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, anaconda, spyder, perceptron

I'm training iris dataset using Perceptron and finding the following error.

> ValueError: The number of class labels must be greater than one.

Code below

```
y = df.iloc[0:100, 4].values
y = np.where(y== 'Iris-setosa', -1,1)
X = df.iloc[0:100, [0,2]].values
ppn = Perceptron(eta0=0.1, n_iter=10)
ppn.fit(X,y)
```

The objective is to fit the data using Sepal length and Petal length for Species type. 
I'm not understanding this error. How should i rectify it?

```
df.head() #for reference
   Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width  Petal.Length  Petal.Width Species
0           5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2  setosa
1           4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2  setosa
2           4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2  setosa
3           4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2  setosa
```

Comment: Please post a reproducible example (we don't know where this class `Perceptron` comes from).

Comment: The problem is with your dataframe. The posted code is just fine. @CarlosCordoba it's Perceptron class from scipy.linear_model

Comment: Yes @LukaszTracewski, the dataframe y had all same values because y = np.where(y== 'Iris-setosa', -1,1) and there was no such value as 'Iris-setosa' in the new dataset i downloaded. stupid me!!. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to predict the species which which in your example has only one value "setosa". You need to have at least to different values.

Comment: Hi, actually there are 2 species: setosa and versicolor in the dataset, which are reflected as -1 and 1 resp. in y dataframe